# React-Navigation: Dynamic Title in TabNavigator. Undefined in not an object

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm just getting started with `React Navigation` and `TabNavigator`.

I have 2 Tabs: ChannelScreen & ListScreen.
When I click on one of the Channels in the ListScreen the Title of ChannelScreen is supposed to be replaced.

**ChannelScreen:**

```
export default class ChannelScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: `${navigation.state.params.title}`,
  })
```

**ListScreen:**

```
export default class ListScreen extends Component {
  handlePress = (channelKey, channelName) => {
    console.log('change channel', channelKey, channelName)
    this.props.navigation.navigate('ChannelScreen', { title: channelName });
  }
render() {
    return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <TouchableOpacity
    style={styles.channelCard}
    onPress={() => {
        this.handlePress('01','Channel 1')
      }}
    >
       <Text>Channel 1</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    )
  }
}
```

(I simplified my code a litte - hope I didn't mess anything up)

If I pass the params in my `StackNavigator`, everything works fine. Though when I try to pass on the Title through the `TabNavigator`, I get this Error:

> Undefined in not an object (evaluating 'navigation.state.params.title')

I also tried `setParams`- I don't get it to work in the `TabNavigator` either. 
Do you have any pointers or suggestions for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it happens because the params is not set from first render, so you need to add conditional rendering to do that,i have tried your code, and got this solution, you can try to change your ChannelScreen to be like this :

```
export default class ChannelScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: navigation.state.params ? `${navigation.state.params.title}` : 'Default Title in Here',
  })
```

i hope it can help you, please notice me if you have an error thanks :)